# Is a contiguous_range always a sized_range?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, language-lawyer, c++20

I have the following question concerning the ranges library in C++20:

Let `std::ranges::contiguous_range<T>` for an *arbitrary* type T.

Can I assume `std::ranges::sized_range<T>`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, not every `contiguous_range` is a `sized_range`.

The simplest example is a null-terminated string. It's contiguous, but we don't know its size in `O(1)` time. And we can easily represent such a thing using sentinels:

```cpp
struct ntbs_sentinel {
    bool operator==(char const* p) const {
        return *p == '\0';
    }
};

struct ntbs {
    char const* p;
    char const* begin() const { return p; }
    ntbs_sentinel end() const { return {}; }
};

static_assert(std::ranges::contiguous_range<ntbs>);
static_assert(!std::ranges::sized_range<ntbs>);
```

---

Another example would be, given some `std::string` object `s` and some predicate `p`, either:

- `s | std::views::take_while(p)`
- `s | std::views::drop_while(p)`

The resulting range here is still contiguous, but we don't know where it ends (in the first case) or where it starts (in the second) so we don't know what its size is.

Comment: One could extract a generalized sentinel there... Just template it, add computed `noexcept`, add `constexpr`, and use cast to `bool` instead of comparison to some literal.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That would only work if the iterator (or the iterator's `value_type`) had a conversion to `bool`, *and* that conversion meant that the end of the list had been reached. Considering how rare this is for ranges, it's probably best to be less generic and more explicit about what you're doing.

Comment: @NicolBolas At least a null_terminated_sequence-sentinel is easy enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Probably not "null" terminated specifically, but terminated by a default-constructed `value_type`.

Comment: @NicolBolas So, two default-sentinels: One stopping at a falsey element, if that doesn't compile a default-constructed one. And one for behavior specific to the iterator it is combined with, so we don't need a custom and potentially dynamic one like in stream-iterators.

Answer (score 11):

Being a `contiguous_range<T>` is insufficient to be considered a `sized_range<T>`, due to the presence of a sentinel. However, if you combine `contiguous_range<T>` with `common_range<T>` (which requires that the sentinel is an iterator), then `sized_range<T>` must also be true.

Here's the logic. A `contiguous_range<T>` is also a `random_access_range<T>`. And a `random_access_range<T>` means in part that [`random_access_iterator<iterator_t<T>>` is true.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator) [`common_range<T>` means that `is_same<iterator_t<T>, sentinel_t<T>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_range). Therefore, `random_access_iterator<sentinel_t<T>>` must also be true.

Now, `random_access_iterator<It>` [imposes a requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator) that `std::sized_sentinel_for<I, I>` is true. Since `iterator_t<T>` and `sentinel_t<T>` are the same type, this means that `std::sized_sentinel_for<sentinel_t<T>, iterator_t<T>>` must also be true.

So, let's look at `sized_range<T>`. This requires that `std::ranges::size(t)` is valid for a `t` of type `T`.

[`ranges::size<T>` is valid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/size) if `T` models `ranges::forward_range<T>` (which it does) and `sentinel_t<T>` and `iterator_t<T>` models `std::sized_sentinel_for<sentinel_t<T>, iterator_t<T>>`.

Which as previously stated, it does.

Answer (score 7):

No.

`contiguous_range` is:

```
template<class T>
concept contiguous_range =
  ranges::random_access_range<T> &&
  std::contiguous_iterator<ranges::iterator_t<T>> &&
  requires(T& t) {
    { ranges::data(t) } ->
      std::same_as<std::add_pointer_t<ranges::range_reference_t<T>>>;
  };
```

and, as you can see, it `requires` `random_access_range`, which is:

```
template<class T>
concept random_access_range =
  ranges::bidirectional_range<T> && std::random_access_iterator<ranges::iterator_t<T>>;
```

which, on the other hand, `requires` `bidirectional_range`, which is:

```
template<class T>
concept bidirectional_range =
  ranges::forward_range<T> && std::bidirectional_iterator<ranges::iterator_t<T>>;
```

which `requires` `forward_range`, that is:

```
template<class T>
concept forward_range =
  range::input_range<T> && std::forward_iterator<ranges::iterator_t<T>>;
```

and that `requires` `input_range`, so it needs:

```
template<class T>
concept input_range =
  ranges::range<T> && std::input_iterator<ranges::iterator_t<T>>;
```

while `range` only `requires` that `std::ranges::begin()` and `std::ranges::end()` are valid for given `T`.

---

You can play a similar game with those `std::XXX_iterator`s. Nowhere there is anything for `std::ranges::size` (which enables `sized_range`).

Comment: FWIW, re your last sentence: You can have an infinite stream of data in the form of a range, but I'm pretty sure you cannot have an infinite stream of data in the form of a _contiguous_ range. :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone correct. After some thought I edited the answer - that last paragraph didn't really add anything to it and could lead to potential confusion, such as the one pointed out by you.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: As far as the iterator model is concerned, you *can* have an "infinite stream of data" that is contiguous. Here, "infinite" merely means that the sentinel never equals any iterator. You may eventually crash due to lack of addressible memory, but from a conceptual range standpoint, it is logically valid.